# Ionic Application not able to update dynamically with database

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm connecting ionic application with MySql database using PHP, all functionalities are working fine but when i upload data in database it is taking atleast hour of time for data updation in ionic application, Please find sample code for the same:

I havent used any sessions and when loading component every time will fire request to fetch data from dabase using PHP, tried placing ngZone but still issue remains same.

```
this.zone.run(() => {
      this.http
      .get('http://localhost:8100/dbcon/retreive-monthcircular.php')
      .subscribe((monthdata : any) =>
      {

         console.dir(monthdata);
         this.loadData = false;
         this.circularmonthdata = monthdata;
         if (this.circularmonthdata == null) {
          this.displayCircular = false;
        } else {
          this.displayCircular = true;
        }
      },
      (error : any) =>
      {
         console.dir(error);
      });
    });
```

Ideally Application should dynamically update

Comment: Does your api `http://localhost:8100/dbcon/retreive-monthcircular.php` returns data immediately?

Comment: Yes but latest uploaded data is not available, when rendering from browser its working fine the issue is after building APK.

Comment: maybe it is because of CORS issue? or try to remote debug with chrome remote devices option

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example

HTML :

`<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button block (click)="getData(myDate)">Get Data</button>`

Bellow is your current data from array we created.

`<ion-item *ngFor="let data of fetchedData">
    Date: {{data.date}} - Description: {{data.description}}
</ion-item>`

your TS:

```
fetchedData = [ // suppose your data looks like this 
  {
    date: '20-02-1990',
    description: 'this is First date'
  },
  {
    date: '21-03-1991',
    description: 'this is Second date'
  }
]
  getData(myDate){
    this.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}; 
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8100/dbcon/retreive-monthcircular.php', {headers: this.headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
        this.fetchedData = data.data; // update your variable it will update data on your view.
    });
  }
```

by clicking on this function will update your data at DOM. Or you should post your HTML and fetched Data from server.